# Excel Solver Error: The objective cell values do not converge

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I've been consistently getting the error above when trying to get the parameters for my logistic regression Does anyone have any ideas why this may be happening?

I see that the solver is making the logit column a value so high that the exponential column can't compute it, is there a way to circumvent this?

[image: Sheet]

[image: Solver parameters]

[image: Solver results]